# Devise Messaging System

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm on Rails 4 and looking for a good `Messaging system` (Inbox, send, recieve etc) for `Devise`. I looked arround and browsed A LOT of sites but cant seem to find something good and developed.

If you know a good gem please share it with me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ruby-toolbox has a few gems for [messaging systems](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/User_Messaging_Systems).

The top one on there is [Mailboxer](https://github.com/ging/mailboxer).

Here is a sample app using it with Devise  https://github.com/RKushnir/mailboxer-app

Comment: Yeah found that too after a while, but struggeling a lot :P